# Не удается получить ответ от микро сервисного приложения java

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, spring-data, микросервисы

При попытке получить ответ от приложения выдается ошибка

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown return value type: java.lang.Long

Но в базу данных все сохраняется.
Вот код контроллера

```
    public Long createBill(@RequestBody BillRequestDTO billRequestDTO){
        return billService.saveBill(billRequestDTO.getAmount(),
                billRequestDTO.getIsOverdraftEnabled(), billRequestDTO.getAccountId());
    }
```

вот код сервиса

```
     Bill bill = new Bill(amount, isOverdraftEnabled, accountId);
     return billRepository.save(bill).getId();
     }
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить @ResponseBody на метод

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.